# Computed property in model with belongsTo returns undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have 3 models.

```
// Product
export default DS.Model.extend({
    content: DS.attr('string'),
    creator: DS.belongsTo('user')
});

// User
export default DS.Model.extend({
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    products: DS.hasMany('product'),
    person: DS.belongsTo('person'),
    fullName: Ember.computed(function() {
        return `${this.get('person.firstname')} ${this.get('person.surname')}`;
    })
});

// Person
export default DS.Model.extend({
    firstname: DS.attr('string'),
    surname: DS.attr('string'),
    users: DS.hasMany('user')
});
```

I try to use this in handlebars.

```
{{#each products as |product|}}
    {{product.creator.fullName}}
{{/each}}
```

As you can see there is a computed property in the `User` model. But it returns always `undefined undefined` because `this.get('person.firstname')` and `this.get('person.surname')` return undefined.

The Ember inspector shows data for each model. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Seems like you would want `fullName` on `Person`, not `User`?  Not your problem, but...

Comment: In fact that causes the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relationships by default are asynchronous and returns [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). That means you don't have data in the moment when you ask it. When you first time ask data it will be loaded and you need to add dependent  keys to your [computed property](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_computed-properties-in-action) to get updated `fullName` when `Person` model will be resolved.

PS. You can take a look to addons like `ember-promise-helpers` to organize asynchronous data in your templates.

```
// User
export default DS.Model.extend({
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    products: DS.hasMany('product'),
    person: DS.belongsTo('person'),

    fullName: Ember.computed('person.{firstname,surname}', function() {
        return `${this.get('person.firstname')} ${this.get('person.surname')}`;
    })
});

// Person
export default DS.Model.extend({
    firstname: DS.attr('string'),
    surname: DS.attr('string'),
    users: DS.hasMany('user')
});
```

Comment: TIL "dependent keys"...  Thanks